# Segue from button

Tags: ios, navigation, swift, push, segue

I have the layout below.

I'm trying to make it so that when you hit the details button, it goes deeper into the navigation stack and shows the detail (3rd VC) view controller.

But when I hit the button, nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for Navigation using Storyboard is Given in this SourceCode

[DemoCode Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5a55dgu9r3wi1p2/test44.zip)

ok Check it

Main thing is that

```
- (IBAction)gotoNext:(id)sender {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mynextviewpush" sender:self];

}
```

Comment: It already has an IBAction associated with it.  I just add `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueid", sender: self)` ?